# Python 3 and mysql through SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Currently:

- SQLAlchemy installed and working (or at least import v0.8.0b2)
- Mysql (v5.5.16)
- Distribute (0.6.34)
- Oracle mysql-python connector
- Python 3.2
- Windows 7 32/64 (note that I installed Python 32bits)

The problem is that MySQLdb or Oursql is required and I didn't managed to get any of them working.

Found [this](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3) but didn't manage to get it working neither.

Edit: If you are aware of an other orm that works with Python3, I'm interested.

Comment: [MySQL-python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4) doesn't seem to support Python 3 for now, but [Oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/index.html) seems to support Pyton 3, and I guess you can get [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL) to work on Python 3.x too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed i saw that oursql should support Python 3 but the installation failed. It told that i'm not using cython. Tried pymysql but don't remember the error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was successful in getting Oracle's MySQL connector for python working with SQLAlchemy on Python 3.3.  Your connection string needs to start with "mysql+mysqlconnector://...".  After I changed my connection string everything (well, simple things) started working.

The MySQL connector docs can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

The package is up on PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/

Here are the SQLAlchemy docs about using the Python connector: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector

Comment: I'll test this but at the time of the question it didn't worked. Maybe they finally made an update. There wasn't any sqlalchemy for 3.3.

Answer (score 13):

For others who arrive here, this should do it:

- pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4  # version avoids Protobuf error
- URI = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://$USER:$PASS@$HOST/$DB'

Answer (score 2):

I tried Oracle's connection, as suggested by @Brad Campbell, but unfortunately it was *extremely* slow, much slower than the "real" `MySQL-Python` connection I had been using with `SQLAlchemy` on Python 2.

After checking SQLAlchemy themselves,

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb

To use `MySQL-Python` on Python 3, they recommend a fork of it, `mysqlclient`,

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

It is available via pip with `pip install mysqlclient`, but there are almost certainly other steps you'll need to do to set it up initially.  After that though, I was seeing the performance go back to what I was used to, which was about 5x faster than with Oracle's connector.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten oursql + SQLAlchemy 0.8.1 + Python 3.3 to work.  Building off of LukeCarrier's port, I modified oursql.c to use the correct import levels, and it worked!  Try this, and be sure to follow the readme:

https://github.com/clintron/py3k-oursql

You may also need to have the latest version of Cython.

Comment: Yes, this works for me, too (using Python 3.2, though). However, I get DBAPIError exceptions when strings contain non-ASCII characters. Is this supposed to be working?

Comment: It should work.  I just successfully inserted a Chinese character (北) through this connector.  Is your database using UTF-8 or latin1?

Comment: It's using UTF-8, and I tried `Unicode(100)`, `String(100)` and `String(100, convert_unicode = True)`. But anyway.. I'll continue to experiment. Good to know that it's supposed to be working. Thank you.