# How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mysql-python

I can connect to my local mysql database from python, and I can create, select from, and insert individual rows.

My question is: can I directly instruct mysqldb to take an entire dataframe and insert it into an existing table, or do I need to iterate over the rows?

In either case, what would the python script look like for a very simple table with ID and two data columns, and a matching dataframe?

Comment: Do you need to use mysqldb, or are you ok with another MySQL connector?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

#### Update:

There is now a [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method, which is the preferred way to do this, rather than `write_frame`:

```
df.to_sql(con=con, name='table_name_for_df', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

*Also note: the syntax may change in pandas 0.14...*

You can set up the connection with [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

```py
from pandas.io import sql
import MySQLdb

con = MySQLdb.connect()  # may need to add some other options to connect
```

Setting the `flavor` of `write_frame` to `'mysql'` means you can write to mysql:

```py
sql.write_frame(df, con=con, name='table_name_for_df', 
                if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

The argument `if_exists` tells pandas how to deal if the table already exists:

> `if_exists: {'fail', 'replace', 'append'}`, default `'fail'`
>            `fail`: If table exists, do nothing.
>            `replace`: If table exists, drop it, recreate it, and insert data.
>            `append`: If table exists, insert data. Create if does not exist.

*Although the [`write_frame` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#sql-queries) currently suggest it only works on sqlite, mysql appears to be supported and in fact there is quite a bit of [mysql testing in the codebase](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/tests/test_sql.py#L223).*

Comment: Andy - any thoughts on how to handle this with pandas 0.20.2's deprecation of the 'mysql' flavor?

Comment: @pshep123 use SQLAlchemy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30653988/1240268 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29356874/1240268 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#engine-connection-examples (an engine rather than connection)

Comment: Excellent, not sure why I didn't figure that from my searches, but that did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Such approach (sql.write_frame) is deprecated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487878/attributeerror-module-pandas-io-sql-has-no-attribute-frame-query/57055400#57055400

Comment: What is the default schema?  From pandas docs: "schemastr, optional

    Specify the schema (if database flavor supports this). If None, use default schema."

Comment: Before I do this, do I need to make empty tables using mySQL syntax or phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 30):

Andy Hayden mentioned the correct function ([`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)). In this answer, I'll give a complete example, which I tested with Python 3.5 but should also work for Python 2.7 (and Python 3.x):

First,  let's create the dataframe:

```
# Create dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
number_of_samples = 10
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'feature1': np.random.random(number_of_samples),
    'feature2': np.random.random(number_of_samples),
    'class':    np.random.binomial(2, 0.1, size=number_of_samples),
    },columns=['feature1','feature2','class'])

print(frame)
```

Which gives:

```
   feature1  feature2  class
0  0.548814  0.791725      1
1  0.715189  0.528895      0
2  0.602763  0.568045      0
3  0.544883  0.925597      0
4  0.423655  0.071036      0
5  0.645894  0.087129      0
6  0.437587  0.020218      0
7  0.891773  0.832620      1
8  0.963663  0.778157      0
9  0.383442  0.870012      0
```

To import this dataframe into a MySQL table:

```
# Import dataframe into MySQL
import sqlalchemy
database_username = 'ENTER USERNAME'
database_password = 'ENTER USERNAME PASSWORD'
database_ip       = 'ENTER DATABASE IP'
database_name     = 'ENTER DATABASE NAME'
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.
                                               format(database_username, database_password, 
                                                      database_ip, database_name))
frame.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='table_name_for_df', if_exists='replace')
```

One trick is that [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) doesn't work with Python 3.x. So instead we use `mysqlconnector`, which may be [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45470868/395857) as follows:

```
pip install mysql-connector==2.1.4  # version avoids Protobuf error
```

Output:

[image]

Note that [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) creates the table as well as the columns if they do not already exist in the database.

Comment: `\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py in __init__(self, drivername, username, password, host, port, database, query)
     69         self.host = host
     70         if port is not None:
---> 71             self.port = int(port)
     72         else:
     73             self.port = None

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
` problem with port number, how to mention port

Comment: @pyd the format of the string to inlclude port is as follows: `'mysql+mysqldb://{user}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}'.format(user='<user>', password='<password>', server='<server>', port='<port>',  database=<'database'>)`

Answer (score 5):

You can  do it by using pymysql:

For example, let's suppose you have a MySQL database with the next user, password, host and port and you want to write in the database 'data_2', **if it is already there or not**.

```
import pymysql
user = 'root'
passw = 'my-secret-pw-for-mysql-12ud'
host =  '172.17.0.2'
port = 3306
database = 'data_2'
```

**If you already have the database created**:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                       port=port,
                       user=user, 
                       passwd=passw,  
                       db=database,
                       charset='utf8')

data.to_sql(name=database, con=conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=False, flavor = 'mysql')
```

**If you do NOT have the database created**, also valid when the database is already there:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, passwd=passw)

conn.cursor().execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {0} ".format(database))
conn = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                       port=port,
                       user=user, 
                       passwd=passw,  
                       db=database,
                       charset='utf8')

data.to_sql(name=database, con=conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=False, flavor = 'mysql')
```

Similar threads:

1. [Writing to MySQL database with pandas using SQLAlchemy, to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631325/writing-to-mysql-database-with-pandas-using-sqlalchemy-to-sql/48116232#48116232)
2. [Writing a Pandas Dataframe to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939716/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-mysql)

Comment: The `name` parameter should be the table name, not the database name.

Comment: The flavor kwarg for to_sql no longer is permitted.

Comment: Thank you! The `index=False` helped me solve the following error: `(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column "index" used in key specification without a key length`

Answer (score 2):

The to_sql method works for me.

However, keep in mind that the it looks like it's going to be deprecated in favor of SQLAlchemy:

```
FutureWarning: The 'mysql' flavor with DBAPI connection is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. MySQL will be further supported with SQLAlchemy connectables. chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2 + 3

#### Prerequesites

- Pandas
- MySQL server
- sqlalchemy
- [pymysql](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): pure python mysql client

#### Code

```
from pandas.io import sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                       .format(user="root",
                               pw="your_password",
                               db="pandas"))
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='table_name', if_exists='replace')
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Create engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://USER_NAME_HERE:PASS_HERE@HOST_ADRESS_HERE/DB_NAME_HERE')

# Create the connection and close it(whether successed of failed)
with engine.begin() as connection:
  df.to_sql(name='INSERT_TABLE_NAME_HERE/INSERT_NEW_TABLE_NAME', con=connection, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me. At first I've created only the database, no predefined table I created.

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
3.7.3

path='glass.data'
df=pd.read_csv(path)
df.head()


!conda install sqlalchemy
!conda install pymysql

pd.__version__
    '0.24.2'

sqlalchemy.__version__
'1.3.20'
```

restarted the Kernel after installation.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE_NAME', echo=False)

try:
df.to_sql(name='glasstable',con=engine,index=False, if_exists='replace')
print('Sucessfully written to Database!!!')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might output your `DataFrame` as a csv file and then use `mysqlimport` to import your csv into your `mysql`.

## EDIT

Seems [pandas's build-in sql util](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html?highlight=sql) provide a `write_frame` function but only works in sqlite.

I found something useful, you might try [this](https://gist.github.com/catawbasam/3164289)

Comment: Thanks, this is how I've been doing this so far. I'm looking for a way to directly insert into mysql without the csv detour.

Answer (score -1):

> df.to_sql(name = "owner", con= db_connection, schema = 'aws', if_exists='replace', index = >True, index_label='id')