# MySQL `Load Data Infile Local` fails for .csv unless I open and save the file first. How can I avoid this step?

Tags: python, mysql, file-upload, csv, pandas

I generate .csv files using a python script by writing a pandas DataFrame `to_csv`, using utf8 encoding.

```
consEx.to_csv(os.path.join(base_dir, "Database/Tables/Consumption Expenditure/consumptionExpenditure.csv"), encoding = 'utf8', index = False)
```

Next, I upload to Amazon RDS MySQL via `Load Data Local Infile`, into a table that has `Charset` also set to utf8.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Consumer.Expenditure (
  ceID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  ceCategory INT NOT NULL,
  year INT NULL,
  countryID INT NOT NULL,
  ceYoY DEC(15,2) NULL,
  dateCreated DATE NOT NULL ,
  lastModified DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  dateDeleted DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (ceID) ,
  CONSTRAINT ce_fk_countries
    FOREIGN KEY (countryID)
    REFERENCES ConsumerAlpha.Countries (countryID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

CHARSET utf8 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

Now, upload ONLY works if I first open and manually save the csv file - same name, same location. Otherwise, it fails without error - just doesn't import anything. However, if I open, save, and close, upload works perfectly.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
INFILE '/Users/xxx/Dropbox/Data/Database/Tables/Consumption Expenditure/consumptionExpenditure.csv'
INTO TABLE Consumer.Expenditure
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ceCategory, year, countryID, ceYoY, dateCreated)
SET dateCreated = NOW();
```

Is there anything I'm missing to avoid this step? For large tables, there may be many .csv files. I've looked around quite a bit, but haven't come across this particular issue anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: "open and manually save the csv file" ... can you describe this more? Does your editor change the file in any way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database) on seconds thoughts, it's perhaps the opposite, nevertheless related.

Answer (score 2):

Considering skipping the CSV step by using `pandas.io.sql.write_frame`.

```
import MySQLdb
conn = Mysqldb.conn(host='...', user='...', passwd='...',db='...')

import pandas.io.sql as psql
psql.write_frame(dataframe, 'TableName', conn, 'mysql')
```

If you are appending to an existing table, use the keyword argument `if_exists='append'`.

Edit: I forgot that @Andy wrote essentially the same answer awhile back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16477603/1221924. As he notes, we added MySQL support but neglected to document it.