# Pandas: Looking up the list of sheets in an excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

The new version of Pandas uses [the following interface](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html#pandas.io.excel.read_excel) to load Excel files:

```
read_excel('path_to_file.xls', 'Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

but what if I don't know the sheets that are available?

For example, I am working with excel files that the following sheets

> Data 1, Data 2 ..., Data N, foo, bar

but I don't know `N` a priori.

Is there any way to get the list of sheets from an excel document in Pandas?

Answer (score 504, accepted):

You can still use the [ExcelFile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#excel-files) class (and the `sheet_names` attribute):

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('foo.xls')

xl.sheet_names  # see all sheet names

xl.parse(sheet_name)  # read a specific sheet to DataFrame
```

*see [docs for parse](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) for more options...*

Comment: Mentioned before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16896091/1240268), but I like to keep a dictionary of DataFrames using `{sheet_name: xl.parse(sheet_name) for sheet_name in xl.sheet_names}`

Comment: Wish I could give you more upvotes, this works across multiple versions of pandas too! (don't know why they like changing the API so often) Thanks for pointing me at the parse function, here is the current link though: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html

Comment: When opening xlsx files, this will fail in pandas 1.1.5. But can be fixed by using `xl = pd.ExcelFile('foo.xls', engine='openpyxl')`. Related on my issue, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-an-excel-xlsx-file)

Answer (score 89):

You should explicitly  specify the second parameter (sheetname) as None. like this:

```
 df = pandas.read_excel("/yourPath/FileName.xlsx", None);
```

"df" are all sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames, you can verify it by run this:

```
df.keys()
```

result like this:

```
[u'201610', u'201601', u'201701', u'201702', u'201703', u'201704', u'201705', u'201706', u'201612', u'fund', u'201603', u'201602', u'201605', u'201607', u'201606', u'201608', u'201512', u'201611', u'201604']
```

please refer pandas doc for more details: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: This unnecessarily parses every sheet as a DataFrame, which is not required. "How to read an xls/xlsx file" is a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16888888/1240268).

Comment: @AndyHayden it might not be efficient, but it might be the best if you care about all the sheets, or you don't care about the additional overhead.

Comment: The named argument is called `sheet_name`. I.e., `df = pandas.read_excel("/yourPath/FileName.xlsx", sheet_name=None, engine='openpyxl')`

Answer (score 24):

> The easiest way to retrieve the sheet-names from an excel (xls., xlsx) is:

```
tabs = pd.ExcelFile("path").sheet_names 
print(tabs)
```

> Then to read and store the data of a particular sheet (say, sheet names are "Sheet1", "Sheet2", etc.), say "Sheet2" for example:

```
data = pd.read_excel("path", "Sheet2") 
print(data)
```

Answer (score 15):

This is the fastest way I have found, inspired by @divingTobi's answer. All The answers based on xlrd, openpyxl or pandas are slow for me, as they all load the whole file first.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # you also need to install "lxml" for the XML parser

with ZipFile(file) as zipped_file:
    summary = zipped_file.open(r'xl/workbook.xml').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(summary, "xml")
sheets = [sheet.get("name") for sheet in soup.find_all("sheet")]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#It will work for Both '.xls' and '.xlsx' by using pandas

import pandas as pd
excel_Sheet_names = (pd.ExcelFile(excelFilePath)).sheet_names

#for '.xlsx' use only  openpyxl

from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_Sheet_names = (load_workbook(excelFilePath, read_only=True)).sheet_names
```

Comment: I believe the method is called ".sheetnames" (without underscore).

Answer (score 4):

If you:

- care about performance
- don't need the data in the file at execution time.
- want to go with conventional libraries vs rolling your own solution

Below was benchmarked on a ~10Mb `xlsx`, `xlsb` file.

#### `xlsx, xls`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def get_sheetnames_xlsx(filepath):
    wb = load_workbook(filepath, read_only=True, keep_links=False)
    return wb.sheetnames
```

*Benchmarks:* ~ **14x speed improvement**

```
# get_sheetnames_xlsx vs pd.read_excel
225 ms ± 6.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
3.25 s ± 140 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### `xlsb`

```
from pyxlsb import open_workbook

def get_sheetnames_xlsb(filepath):
  with open_workbook(filepath) as wb:
     return wb.sheets
```

*Benchmarks:* ~ **56x speed improvement**

```
# get_sheetnames_xlsb vs pd.read_excel
96.4 ms ± 1.61 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
5.36 s ± 162 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*Notes:*

- This is a good resource -
  http://www.python-excel.org/
- `xlrd` is no longer maintained as of 2020

Answer (score 3):

I have tried xlrd, pandas, openpyxl and other such libraries and all of them seem to take exponential time as the file size increase as it reads the entire file. The other solutions mentioned above where they used 'on_demand' did not work for me. If you just want to get the sheet names initially, the following function works for xlsx files.

```
def get_sheet_details(file_path):
    sheets = []
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(file_path)[-1])[0]
    # Make a temporary directory with the file name
    directory_to_extract_to = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name)
    os.mkdir(directory_to_extract_to)

    # Extract the xlsx file as it is just a zip file
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)
    zip_ref.close()

    # Open the workbook.xml which is very light and only has meta data, get sheets from it
    path_to_workbook = os.path.join(directory_to_extract_to, 'xl', 'workbook.xml')
    with open(path_to_workbook, 'r') as f:
        xml = f.read()
        dictionary = xmltodict.parse(xml)
        for sheet in dictionary['workbook']['sheets']['sheet']:
            sheet_details = {
                'id': sheet['@sheetId'],
                'name': sheet['@name']
            }
            sheets.append(sheet_details)

    # Delete the extracted files directory
    shutil.rmtree(directory_to_extract_to)
    return sheets
```

Since all xlsx are basically zipped files, we extract the underlying xml data and read sheet names from the workbook directly which takes a fraction of a second as compared to the library functions.

*Benchmarking: (On a 6mb xlsx file with 4 sheets)*

**Pandas, xlrd:** 12 seconds

**openpyxl:** 24 seconds

**Proposed method:** 0.4 seconds

Since my requirement was just reading the sheet names, the unnecessary overhead of reading the entire time was bugging me so I took this route instead.

Comment: What are the modules you are using?

Comment: @Daniel I have used only `zipfile` which is an in-built module and `xmltodict` which I used to convert the XML into an easily iterable dictionary. Although you can look at @divingTobi's answer below where you can read the same file without actually extracting the files within.

Comment: When I tried openpyxl with the read_only flag it is significantly faster (200X faster for my 5 MB file). `load_workbook(excel_file).sheetnames` averaged 8.24s where `load_workbook(excel_file, read_only=True).sheetnames` averaged 39.6ms.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @dhwanil_shah 's answer, you do not need to extract the whole file. With `zf.open` it is possible to read from a zipped file directly.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import zipfile

def xlsxSheets(f):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(f)

    f = zf.open(r'xl/workbook.xml')

    l = f.readline()
    l = f.readline()
    root = ET.fromstring(l)
    sheets=[]
    for c in root.findall('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}sheets/*'):
        sheets.append(c.attrib['name'])
    return sheets
```

The two consecutive `readline`s are ugly, but the content is only in the second line of the text. No need to parse the whole file.

This solution seems to be much faster than the `read_excel` version, and most likely also faster than the full extract version.

Comment: No, .xls is a completely different file format, so I would not expect this code to work.

Answer (score 3):

if you read excel file

```
dfs = pd.ExcelFile('file')
```

then use

```
dfs.sheet_names
dfs.parse('sheetname')
```

another variant

```
df = pd.read_excel('file', sheet_name='sheetname')
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

sheets = load_workbook(excel_file, read_only=True).sheetnames
```

For a 5MB Excel file I'm working with, `load_workbook` without the `read_only` flag took 8.24s. With the `read_only` flag it only took 39.6 ms. If you still want to use an Excel library and not drop to an xml solution, that's much faster than the methods that parse the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

1. With the load_workbook readonly option, what was earlier seen as a execution seen visibly waiting for many seconds happened with milliseconds. The solution could however be still improved.

   ```
    import pandas as pd
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    class ExcelFile:

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            ........
            .....
            self._SheetNames = list(load_workbook(self._name,read_only=True,keep_links=False).sheetnames)
   ```
2. The Excelfile.parse takes the same time as reading the complete xls in order of 10s of sec. This result was obtained with windows 10 operating system with below package versions

   ```
    C:\>python -V
    Python 3.9.1

    C:\>pip list
    Package         Version
    --------------- -------
    et-xmlfile      1.0.1
    numpy           1.20.2
    openpyxl        3.0.7
    pandas          1.2.3
    pip             21.0.1
    python-dateutil 2.8.1
    pytz            2021.1
    pyxlsb          1.0.8
    setuptools      49.2.1
    six             1.15.0
    xlrd            2.0.1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

path = "\\DB\\Expense\\reconcile\\"

file_name = "202209-v01.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(path + file_name, None)
print(df)

sheet_names = list(df.keys())

# print last sheet name
print(sheet_names[len(sheet_names)-1])

last_month = df.get(sheet_names[len(sheet_names)-1])
print(last_month)
```

Answer (score 1):

If using `pd.read_excel()` with `sheet_name=None` to read sheet names, setting `nrows=0` can significantly boost speeds.

Benchmarking on an 8MB XLSX file with nine sheets:

```py
%timeit pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', sheet_name=None, nrows=0).keys()
>>> 145 ms ± 50.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', sheet_name=None).keys()
>>> 16.5 s ± 2.04 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that (as you might expect) `pandas` stops reading a sheet once it reaches `nrows` ([reference](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47290#issuecomment-1153003412)).