# Import using Python - multiple excel files into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I want to loop through a directory and find specific xlsx files and then put them each into separate pandas dataframe. The thing here is that I also want all sheets in those excel files to be in the dataframe.

Below is a sample of code that I implemented, I just need to add the logic to pick all sheets:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

path = 'path_to_file'

files = glob(path + '/*file*.xlsx')

get_df = lambda f: pd.read_excel(f)

dodf = {f: get_df(f) for f in files}

dodf[files[2]] --- dictionary of dataframes
```

Comment: I have already created a dictionary to access each dataframe. So the current method should be fine, i.e. in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977540/pandas-looking-up-the-list-of-sheets-in-an-excel-file) in Pandas you still have access to the `ExcelFile` class, which loads the file creating an object.

This object has a `.sheet_names` property which gives you a list of sheet names in the current file.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('foo.xls')
xl.sheet_names  # list of all sheet names
```

To actually handle the import of the specific sheet, use `.parse(sheet_name)` on the object of the imported Excel file:

```
xl.parse(sheet_name)  # read a specific sheet to DataFrame
```

For your code something like:

```
get_df = lambda f: pd.ExcelFile(f)
dodf = {f: get_df(f) for f in files}
```

...gives you `dodf` a dictionary of `ExcelFile` objects.

```
filename = 'yourfilehere.xlsx'
a_valid_sheet = dodf[filename].sheet_names[0] # First sheet
df = dodf[filename].parse(sheet_name)
```

Comment: I do not want to manually input the filename. Is there a way to get it from the dictionary dodf that I have created? I am completely new to Python so I do not know as such how it all works.

Comment: yep — but you need you change your `pd.read_excel(f)` to `pd.ExcelFile(f)`. Once that is done, each object will have the `.sheet_names` attribute which is a list of sheets in that file.

Comment: Yes, I already did. But then, I have to individually parse each of the sheet into the dataframe right?

Comment: @ManasJani that's right. But you can iterate over the list of `sheet_names` to do this, e.g. `for sheet in your_xls_obj.sheetnames:  df = your_xls_obj.parse(sheet)`