# how to concatenate multiple excel sheets from the same file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a big excel file that contains many different sheets. All the sheets have the same structure like:

```
Name
col1  col2  col3  col4
1     1     2     4
4     3     2     1
```

- How can I concatenate (vertically) all these sheets in `Pandas` without having to name each of them manually? If these were files, I could use `glob` to obtain a list of files in a directory. But here, for excel sheets, I am lost.
- Is there a way to create a variable in the resulting dataframe that identifies the sheet name from which the data comes from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None, skiprows=1)
```

this will return you a dictionary of DFs, which you can easily concatenate using `pd.concat(dfs)` or as @jezrael has already posted in his answer:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None, skiprows=1))
```

**sheet_name**: None -> All sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames

**UPDATE:**

> Is there a way to create a variable in the resulting dataframe that
> identifies the sheet name from which the data comes from?

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None, skiprows=1)
```

assuming we've got the following dict:

```
In [76]: dfs
Out[76]:
{'d1':    col1  col2  col3  col4
 0     1     1     2     4
 1     4     3     2     1, 'd2':    col1  col2  col3  col4
 0     3     3     4     6
 1     6     5     4     3}
```

Now we can add a new column:

```
In [77]: pd.concat([df.assign(name=n) for n,df in dfs.items()])
Out[77]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4 name
0     1     1     2     4   d1
1     4     3     2     1   d1
0     3     3     4     6   d2
1     6     5     4     3   d2
```

Comment: Then `pd.concat(dfs.values())` yields the result.

Comment: nice but how can I get rid of the `Name` super column? I thought I could use some read_excel (skip = 1) somewhere with the dictionary?

Comment: @blacksite, yes, thank you. I thought OP knows it already... ;-)

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, use `skiprows=1`

Comment: @MaxU just a little change if you can. Is there a way to create a variable in the resulting dataframe that identifies the sheet name from which the data comes from?

Comment: say col4 that is sheet1 sheet1 sheet1 sheet2 sheet2 etc

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, glad i could help :)

Comment: Note that this should now read `dfs = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None, skiprows=1)`

(Note the underscore in sheet_name)

Answer (score 5):

Taking a note from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977540/pandas-looking-up-the-list-of-sheets-in-an-excel-file):

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')

names = file.sheet_names  # see all sheet names

df = pd.concat([file.parse(name) for name in names])
```

Results:

```
df
Out[6]: 
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

Then you can run `df.reset_index()`, to, well, reset the index.

Edit: [`pandas.ExcelFile.parse`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html) is, according to the pandas docs:

> Equivalent to read_excel(ExcelFile, ...) See the read_excel docstring for more info on accepted parameters

Comment: thanks but why using the `file.parse` instead of some `read.excel?`

Comment: See above, please.

Comment: great. thanks guys but I had to give this one to the fastest one! :)

Answer (score 4):

First add parameter `sheetname=None` for `dict` of `DataFrames` and `skiprows=1` for omit first row and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for `MultiIndex DataFrame`.

Last use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from first level:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel('multiple_sheets.xlsx', sheetname=None, skiprows=1))
df = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('filenames').reset_index()
```

Comment: thanks jezrael. same issue, how can I get rid of the first line for every sheet here?

Comment: `skiprows=1` should help.

Comment: great. thanks guys but I had to give this one to the fastest one! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
file_save_location='myfolder'                                
file_name='filename'

location = ''myfolder1'
os.chdir(location)
files_xls = glob.glob("*.xls*")
excel_names=[f for f in files_xls]
sheets = pd.ExcelFile(files_xls[0]).sheet_names
def combine_excel_to_dfs(excel_names, sheet_name):
    sheet_frames = [pd.read_excel(x, sheet_name=sheet_name) for x in excel_names]
    combined_df = pd.concat(sheet_frames).reset_index(drop=True)
    return combined_df

i = 0

while i < len(sheets):
    process = sheets[i]
    consolidated_file= combine_excel_to_dfs(excel_names, process)
    consolidated_file.to_csv(file_save_location+file_name+'.csv')
    i = i+1
else:
    "we done on consolidation part"
```

Comment: Would be better if you could edit the post with some description followed by the code.