# Python|data aggregation| Multiple Excel Files

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have approximately 1000+ excel files, each excel file contains several sheets. I am looking towards building an aggregation of a single type of sheet from each excel file into a single spreadsheet on Python. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: While the docs for Office365 say the number of sheets is only limited by your RAM https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3
this might be too much for your computer.
would you settle for one file per sheet?

Comment: you can use pandas to read all the sheets https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977609/1265980 write them out in any format.

Comment: @Ereli thanks for your response.