# Transforming multiple dataframes with pandas using a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently doing a project where i have to make some transformations and cleaning from an excel file that has the same table in each sheet only that each sheet is representing a different month (different values in the tables).

Therefore the code that will make the transformations is the same only for a different sheet.

```
df_at_jan  = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Spiros/Desktop/Reporting.xlsx",
                      sheet_name='Jan 2018')
df_at_feb  = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Spiros/Desktop/Reporting.xlsx",
                          sheet_name='Feb 2018')

df_at_jan.drop([0,1,2],axis=0)
df_at_jan.columns = df_at_jan.iloc[3]

df_at_feb.drop([0,1,2],axis=0)
df_at_feb.columns = df_at_feb.iloc[3]
```

Of course i have to do this for all the months and i was wondering how i can do this with a for loop in order not to re-create the code for every different month.

I am very new to Python so any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test because you don't give a data example, but the according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521726/5847854) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977609/5847854) answers, you can try:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Spiros/Desktop/Reporting.xlsx')

sheets = xl.sheet_names

df_array = []

for sheet in sheets:
  df_temp = pd.read_excel(xl , sheet)
  df_temp = df_temp.drop([0,1,2],axis=0)
  df_temp.columns = df_temp.iloc[3]

  df_array.append(df_temp)
```

The data of each month will be in a position of the array.

If you need all the data became a single DataFrame, do:

```
df = pd.concat(df_array, ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) create function

```
def read_one_month(sheet_name):
   df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Spiros/Desktop/Reporting.xlsx",
                      sheet_name=sheet_name)
   df.drop([0,1,2],axis=0, inplace = True)
   return df
```

2) define array of sheet names and run a loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(None)
for sheet_name in ['Jan 2018','Feb 2018']:
   df = pd.concat([df, read_one_month(sheet_name)], axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
```