# Getting sheet names from a large Excel file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using Python 3.7 and using OpenPyxl to read the sheet names from a large excel workbook (29MB) with 10 tabs.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='h:\\Master_Portfoliio.xlsx')
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

The code above works for smaller files but when I use the same code for this file, the code just hangs.  I would like to read the sheet names and then remove a tab and then copy a tab from another excel workbook into this workbook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977609/3765034 - Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `read_only = True` flag?

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='h:\\Master_Portfoliio.xlsx', read_only = True)
```