# create multiple dataframes in loop and write to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, append

I am running a loop over a function that produces a dataframe, that looks like this:

```
        Prd1    Prd2     Prd3    Prd4    Prd5    Prd6
Loc1    0        0        0        0       0       0
Loc2    0        0        0        0       0       0
Loc3    0      30.61      0        0   319.58   430.87  
Loc4    0        0        0        0       0    120.73
Loc5    0        0        0        0       0       0
Loc6    78.21  822.36     0        0       0       0
```

I want to run the function multiple times, to produce a series of dataframes to then analyse or visualise evolution over time.For this it would be ideal to have them all in one excel workbook. However I am struggling with this.
I have tried

```
for case in CASES:
    B= A[case]
    result = function(B)
    print(result)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('results.xlsx') as writer:  # doctest: +SKIP
        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='case_'+str(case))
```

my hope was that this would write the different results into the same spreadsheet. However as a result the spreadsheet only contains a tab with the last case.
I can see how the above being within the CASES loop will overwrite the existing sheet each time. 
Is there a function to preserve the sheets that already exist and "append" any new sheet to the existing workbook?
Thanks in advance.
regards P.

Comment: you need all you created data frames save into single csv file?

Comment: ***"loop will overwrite the existing sheet each time."***: First aggregate in a `df` then **write once**

Comment: Move the opening of the `pd.ExcelWriter` outside the for loop so it gets opened and closed once with sheets in it, rather than overwriting it every iteration

Comment: Jon Clements, you are a star, this worked like a treat. :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977540/pandas-looking-up-the-list-of-sheets-in-an-excel-file), you can retrieve list of sheet names before starting your loop and check for existing sheets and skip them.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('results.xlsx')
existing_sheets = xl.sheet_names

for case in CASES:
    if f'cast_{str(case)}' in existing_sheets:
        continue
    B= A[case]
    result = function(B)
    print(result)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('results.xlsx') as writer:  # doctest: +SKIP
        result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'case_{str(case)}')
```