# Choose A Specific Sheet In Excel Containing a String Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm currently creating a dataframe from an excel spreadsheet in Pandas. For most of the files, they only contain 1 sheet. However, with some of the files that I have the sheet is not the first sheet. However, all of the sheets in all of the files have the same format. They have 'ITD_XXX_XXXX'. Is there a way to input into pandas to select the sheet that has the form.

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name = contains('ITD_')
```

Here pandas would only select data from the sheet that has the string 'ITD_' in front of it?

Cheers.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977609/10291291

Comment: So the way I identify it is if  the sheet_name contains the specific string 'ITD_' as the other X's can change and it's not possible to keep track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275384/16606307) would probably give you what you need.

Bring in the file as an Excelfile before reading it as a dataframe. Get the Sheet_names, and then extract the sheet_name that has 'ITD_'.

```
excel = pd.ExcelFile("your_excel.xlsx")
excel.sheet_names
# ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"]
for n in excel.sheet_names:
    if n.startswith('ITD_'):
        sheetname = n
        break
df = excel.parse(sheetname)
```