# PyCharm giving valueerror when trying to read sheets in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using

```
df = pd.read_excel('FileA.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheetc')
```

to read excel data using PyCharm. It is working for specific sheets in the workbook, but for other sheets in the same workbook I am getting this error:

ValueError: Worksheet named 'sheetc' not found.

Does anyone know why this could be, please?

Comment: You can check to see what sheet names Pandas is reading from the Excel sheet and use the relevant one of choice via: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977540/pandas-looking-up-the-list-of-sheets-in-an-excel-file