# How to create pandas dataframes with sheet name in one pass

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have excel file with multiple sheets and I have to create dataframes for each sheet using `pd.read_excel`. Post creation of dataframe I'd like to set `header`, `set_index` and drop few rows.

Is it possible to write a function to perform above operations in one go and create dataframes as sheet name?

Trying with

```
df=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',sheetname="",header=0,skiprows=[1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have dictionary with **keys** as **sheet names** and their corresponding **values** as the **dataframe**.
To achieve this, simply pass **None** to **`sheet_name`** inside the `pandas.read_excel` function.

```
df=pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',sheet_name=None,header=0,skiprows=[1,2,3])
print(type(df))
#--> <class 'dict'>
df.keys()
#--> dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']) # assuming Sheet1 and Sheet2 are the two sheet names of file.xlsx
print(type(df['Sheet1']))
#--> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

As you wanted to have the variable names as sheet names, add below:

```
for key in df.keys():
    globals()[key] = df[key] # now you will have Sheet name as variables
print(type(Sheet1))
#--> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Let me know if this suffice your request

Comment: Thanks Shrey for the answer. Even I had this in my mind. How do we assign Sheet1, Sheet2 as dataframes with unique name (not using df['Sheet1']) My requirement is to read excel and create dataframe for each sheet.

Comment: you want Sheet1 as a variable name ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you get the sheet names then you can build that function. look up [Pandas: Looking up the list of sheets in an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977540/pandas-looking-up-the-list-of-sheets-in-an-excel-file)