# Excel file to dictionary

Tags: excel, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an excel file which contains 2 columns and I want to convert these columns to the dictionary using the header as key and rows as values.

```
file1.xlxs

name      price
Merry     5000
John      6500
Nat       4800
```

The dictionary should be like this:

```
List1 =  {'name':['Merry,John,Nat'],'price':['5000,6500,4800']}
```

Please help?

Comment: Is that what they're calling a dictionary now-a-days?

Comment: Using Pandas we can do it. Check out this answer-https://stackoverflow.com/a/16896091/6561141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas` library for this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("path to your excel file")

list1 = df.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Here is documentation for [df.to_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)