# How to split a column using a delimiter while still retaining its value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataset as shown below:

```
Cola                 colb
1.2/1.4/1.5/1.6      A
3.3/5.6              B
```

I want to have one column

```
COlA Colb
1.2   A
1.4   A
1.5   A
1.6   A
3.3   B
5.6   B
```

How do I do this in python

Comment: What format do you have the initial dataset in? What have you tried so far? Post some code.

Comment: Are you using `pandas` and this data is in a DataFrame? Or is what you're presenting a native excel spreadsheet and you need to read from that?

Comment: Please show what you've tried and ask a more specific question. As your question stands, it's really difficult to understand what part of this problem you are having trouble with, or any of the context of your roblem. If it's basic Python knowledge you lack (opening a file, reading text, etc) then I recommend searching some online Python documentation and tutorial resources.

Answer (score 2):

[Import as a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888888/how-to-read-a-xlsx-file-using-the-pandas-library-in-ipython), and use `str.split` and `explode`:

```
df['Cola'] = df.Cola.str.split('/')
df.explode('Cola')

  Cola colb
0  1.2    A
0  1.4    A
0  1.5    A
0  1.6    A
1  3.3    B
1  5.6    B
```

Comment: Almost beat you to it! Happy to have thought the same way as you!

Comment: Yeah... was thinking along the lines of `df.assign(version=df.Cola.str.split('/')).explode('version')` that way you can also avoid overwriting the original DF frame and it's something to check against... but it doesn't look like that's required here...

Comment: Thank you for this. However I receive blank values after using split in cola...Any particular reason for that

Comment: Please share a sample of the actual dataframe @rudra

Comment: Actual DF: small_area                                                                           Median_BER
217099001/217112002/217112003/217112005/217112   212.9
047041005/047041001/047041004/047041002/047041.  271.3
157041002/157041004/157041003/157041001/157129.  222

Comment: After Split I see below:small_area  Median_BER
NaN  212.9
NaN 271.3
NaN 222.5