# How to make a file with combination of multiple files with different extensions(xlsx, csv)?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How can I combine multiple files with different extensions (e.g., xlsx and csv) into one file csv or excel using Python?

For example, suppose I have the following files:

Folder_A/a1.csv
Folder_B/b1.xlsx
Folder_B/b2.xlsx

I want to combine these in row wise.

Here is my current working code but it is not the smart way to write each file name.
[image]

Comment: Suppose we have a/a1.csv, b/b1.xlsx and b/b2.xlsx, are you looking to concatenate the rows in all 3 files one below the other? Could you edit the description to explain how you want to combine these files please?

Comment: please check my edited explanation once:)

Answer (score 1):

1. For file handling I recommend using the `pathlib` built-in python module: [pathlib examples](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-start-using-pathlib-as-an-alternative-to-the-os-module-d9eccd994745). Use the `glob` method to fetch all files with a given ending - .csv and .xslx
2. Next you can use `pandas` to open the csv and .xslx files - check these examples [for csv files](https://pythonbasics.org/read-csv-with-pandas/), [for excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888888/how-to-read-a-xlsx-file-using-the-pandas-library-in-ipython)
3. Once you load the data into dataframes, you can combine them into one dataframe. If necessary do some data manipulation on the columns.
4. And lastly you can export the combined dataframe into a csv file - use the `pd.to_csv()` method - [documentation on the method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)