Add sensitivity label to Excel files stored inside a folder?
I wish to add sensitivity label to all Excel files stored inside a folder. I created code with some user's reply from stack and modified it to match my use case.
The issue is I have 240 files inside folder, and while this method works for opening, saving, and closing individual files, it takes a lot of time and was slowing my PC.
How can I optimize this code? Maybe by running as a hidden process where the code runs without opening the Excel file?
import xlwings as xw
import os

def change_sensitivity_label(folder_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            try:
                wb = xw.Book(file_path)
                labelinfo = wb.api.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
                labelinfo.AssignmentMethod = 2
                labelinfo.Justification = 'init'
                labelinfo.LabelId = 'd5688d38-24b0-47bd-b6ed-0cb1b7409201'
                wb.api.SensitivityLabel.SetLabel(labelinfo, labelinfo)
                wb.save()
                wb.close()
                print(f"Sensitivity label added to {filename}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")

# Specify the folder path containing Excel files
folder_path = r"C:\Users\NaHa\Downloads\April-VendorSplittingApp-test1"
change_sensitivity_label(folder_path)


So, you want to run the opening, saving and closing in hidden way, without showing the end user?

@HariPN Yes, it is a way I thought which would help in optimization. If there's any other way to optimize this code better, then that idea is also appreciated.

Please make sure to re-read the question again after writing as a user perspective. So, that we can also be clear with the question.

Using a context manager can help if you are getting zombie Excel processes remaining. Also you can set 'visible' to false which might speed things up by not opening the Excel app.

Have you tested pandas? I have not worked with .xlsx files, but it seems possible there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66371322/4601890

My solution is based on the fact that xlsx files are in reality zip files. First, unzip the Excel file which already has desired sensitivity label:
unzip myfile.xlsx -d myfile

Each company has different sensitivity ID, so you have to use your xlsx file. Then, copy content of docProps/custom.xml into the code below (e.g. into variable xml_content_restricted):
"""Change sensitivity label of xlsx files in folder."""
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
import zipfile

xml_content_confidential = """<?xml version="1.0"
"""

xml_content_internal = """<?xml version="1.0"
"""

xml_content_public = """<?xml version="1.0"
"""

xml_content_restricted = """<?xml version="1.0"
"""


def process_xlsx_files(
    folder_path: str,
    filenames_to_remove: list[str],
    xml_content: str,
        ) -> None:
    """
    Process XLSX files in the specified folder by replacing 'custom.xml'.

    Args:
        folder_path (str): Path to the folder containing XLSX files.
        filenames_to_remove (list[str]): List of filenames to remove from XLSX.
        xml_content (str): New sensitivity label to insert.
    """
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            remove_from_zip(file_path, *filenames_to_remove)
            with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'a') as zipwrite:
                zipwrite.writestr('docProps/custom.xml', xml_content)


def remove_from_zip(zipfname: str, *filenames: str) -> None:
    """
    Remove specified files from a ZIP archive.

    Args:
        zipfname (str): Path to the ZIP archive.
        filenames (str): Filenames to remove from the archive.
    """
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    tempname = os.path.join(tempdir, 'new.zip')
    copy_files_excluding(zipfname, tempname, filenames)
    shutil.move(tempname, zipfname)
    shutil.rmtree(tempdir)


def copy_files_excluding(
    zipfname: str,
    tempname: str,
    filenames: tuple[str, ...],
        ) -> None:
    """
    Copy files from one ZIP archive to another, excluding specified filenames.

    Args:
        zipfname (str): Path to the source ZIP archive.
        tempname (str): Path to the destination ZIP archive.
        filenames (tuple): Filenames to exclude from copying.
    """
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfname, 'r') as zipread:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(tempname, 'w') as zipwrite:
            for file_in_zip in zipread.infolist():
                if file_in_zip.filename not in filenames:
                    data_to_copy = zipread.read(file_in_zip.filename)
                    zipwrite.writestr(file_in_zip, data_to_copy)


# Example usage:
file_to_insert = xml_content_restricted
folder_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
filenames_to_remove = ['docProps/custom.xml']
process_xlsx_files(folder_path, filenames_to_remove, file_to_insert)

It runs pretty fast for me, but since I was already in it, I prepared a similar PowerShell script in my repository on GitHub. I then use it as bat file.
