# PyMySQL Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_sql'

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm new to coding and this my first project. So far I've pieced together what I have through Googling, Tutorials and Stack.

I'm trying to add data from a pandas df of scraped RSS feeds to a remote sql database. I've been using a combo of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806649/write-pandas-dataframe-in-to-mysql-database) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database?noredirect=1&lq=1) to fix my error but the answers don't seem to work with my problem.

Does anyone have a potential solution to the error:

> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        19 cursor.execute(sql)
>        20 
>   ---> 21 sql.to_sql(df, con=conn, name='rsstracker', if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')
>        22 
>        23 # disconnect from server
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_sql'

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import sql
import feedparser
import time

rawrss = ['http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/front_page/rss.xml',
          'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss/',
          'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/feeds/index.xml',
          'http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch/',
         ]

posts = []
for url in rawrss:
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    for post in feed.entries:
        posts.append((post.title, post.link, post.summary))
df = pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title', 'link', 'summary']) # pass data to init

import pymysql

# Open database connection
db = pymysql.connect(host="host", port=##, user="username", password="password", db="sql#######" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()


# Drop table if it already exist using execute() method.
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rsstracker")

# Create table as per requirement
sql = """CREATE TABLE rsstracker(
   article_title  varchar(255),
   article_url  varchar(1000),
   article_summary varchar(1000))"""

cursor.execute(sql)

sql.to_sql(df, con=conn, name='rsstracker', if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: Error seems clear as `to_sql` is a pandas dataframe method but you are running it on a sql string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line should be :

```
df.to_sql(con=db, name='rsstracker', if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')
```

But you may need to use SQLAlchemy to make this export possible ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html))

---

You can try to use SQLAlchemy with pymysql like in the following lines :

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>')
engine.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rsstracker")
engine.execute("""CREATE TABLE rsstracker(
   article_title  varchar(255),
   article_url  varchar(1000),
   article_summary varchar(1000))""")


df.to_sql(con=engine, name='rsstracker', if_exists='append', , flavor='mysql')
```

Comment: I've tried this and now get the error: 'ValueError: database flavor mysql is not supported'
Why do you think I may need SQLAlchemy? Is there an issue with the way I'm approaching the problem?

Comment: it seems other flavors are not supported, so i guess you should switch to SQLAlchemy, or export the datas from dataframes with another way

Comment: do I swap 'pymysql' with 'SQLAlchemy'?

Comment: @NickDuddy, could you try with the edited solution ?

Comment: Just tried it, got the following error after I removed the : from the port as I kept getting int error.  '"OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sql8.freemysqlhosting.net[3306]' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")"'

Comment: Just changed '@<host>[:<port>]' to '@<host>:<port>'. Now getting a different error:

'UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 151: ordinal not in range(256)'

Comment: @NickDuddy i think you can resolve this by passing an option at the end of the `create_engine` : `engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>[:<port>]/<dbname>?charset=utf8')`

Comment: check in this answer, maybe you need to specify encoding too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33443380/6655211

Comment: that has solved that encoding problem. Now have an error that looks like this: 'InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'index' in 'field list'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO rsstracker (`index`, title, link, summary) VALUES (%(index)s, %(title)s, %(link)s, %(summary)s)'] [parameters:'  it then goes on to display all the elements from the feed one after the other.

Comment: check the names you choose to create the table, maybe add an `index` field, then it was `article_title` instead of `title`, same for the next columns

Comment: I've set a date index and changed the column headers. I got a different error relating to the content in the summery section. So i've added this as a variable 'summary = 'text''. And the content now goes into the data base. Thanks for you help with this.

Comment: @NickDuddy  glad you achieve what you want, thanks for the feedback