# pandas: unwanted format result from groupby... How do I groupby().sum() to give tabular structure

Tags: group-by, pandas

I've searched through the pandas docs and unfortunately, I could not find the answer.

Essentially, after some data wrangling, I have the dataframe

```
    ticker_id          close_date           sector  sector_index
0           1 2014-02-28 00:00:00   Consumer Goods     31.106653
1           1 2014-02-27 00:00:00   Consumer Goods     30.951213
2           2 2014-02-28 00:00:00   Consumer Goods     19.846387
3           2 2014-02-27 00:00:00   Consumer Goods     19.671747
4           3 2014-02-28 00:00:00   Consumer Goods   1208.552000
5           3 2014-02-27 00:00:00   Consumer Goods   1193.352000
6           4 2014-02-28 00:00:00   Consumer Goods      9.893989
7           4 2014-02-27 00:00:00   Consumer Goods      9.857385
8           5 2014-02-28 00:00:00   Consumer Goods     52.196757
9           5 2014-02-27 00:00:00   Consumer Goods     53.101520
10          6 2014-02-28 00:00:00         Services      5.449554
11          6 2014-02-27 00:00:00         Services      5.440019
12          7 2014-02-28 00:00:00  Basic Materials   4149.237000
13          7 2014-02-27 00:00:00  Basic Materials   4130.704000
```

And I ran groupby

```
df_all2 = df_all.groupby(['close_date','sector']).sum()
print df_all2
```

And the outcome is this

```
                            ticker_id  sector_index
close_date sector                                  
2014-02-27 Basic Materials          7   4130.704000
           Consumer Goods          15   1306.933865
           Services                 6      5.440019
2014-02-28 Basic Materials          7   4149.237000
           Consumer Goods          15   1321.595786
           Services                 6      5.449554
```

But in this form, I can't upload to mysql properly.  So in order to upload to mysql properly, I need to do this and a few other things.

```
data2 = list(tuple(x) for x in df_all2.values)
```

but data2 has meaningless garbage.

To make a long story short, how can I get groupby to give me the following outcome (where the close_date are all filled in properly and the column headings are tabular).

```
close_date sector           ticker_id  sector_index
2014-02-27 Basic Materials          7   4130.704000
2014-02-27 Consumer Goods          15   1306.933865
2014-02-27 Services                 6      5.440019
2014-02-28 Basic Materials          7   4149.237000
2014-02-28 Consumer Goods          15   1321.595786
2014-02-28 Services                 6      5.449554
```

Also, to help the community, how should I modify the title so that other pandas users facing this issue can find your solution, too?  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) on a MultiIndex before using [`to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)*:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['close_date','sector']).sum().reset_index()
Out[11]:
  close_date           sector  ticker_id  sector_index
0 2014-02-27  Basic Materials          7   4130.704000
1 2014-02-27   Consumer Goods         15   1306.933865
2 2014-02-27         Services          6      5.440019
3 2014-02-28  Basic Materials          7   4149.237000
4 2014-02-28   Consumer Goods         15   1321.595786
5 2014-02-28         Services          6      5.449554
```

Alternatively you can use as_index=False in the groupby:

```
In [12]: df.groupby(['close_date','sector'], as_index=False).sum()
Out[12]:
  close_date           sector  ticker_id  sector_index
0 2014-02-27  Basic Materials          7   4130.704000
1 2014-02-27   Consumer Goods         15   1306.933865
2 2014-02-27         Services          6      5.440019
3 2014-02-28  Basic Materials          7   4149.237000
4 2014-02-28   Consumer Goods         15   1321.595786
5 2014-02-28         Services          6      5.449554
```

**Note: this should be fixed from 0.14 onwards i.e. you should be able to save a MultiIndex to sql.*

See [How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database/16477603#16477603).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the link to "how to insert pandas to mysqldb".  I wasn't able to get it to work so I am using pymysql package.  Do you know if pandas work with pymysql?

Comment: @vt2424253 I think some users here have said that it does.