# Pandas Write table to MySQL: "unable to rollback"

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I need help to get this working. I have a `pd.DataFrame (df)`, which I need to load to a MySQL database. I don't understand what the error message means and how to fix it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is what I tried:

```
    import MySQLdb
    from pandas.io import sql

    #METHOD 1 
    db=MySQLdb.connect(host="***",port=***,user="***",passwd="***",db="***")
    df.to_sql(con=db, name='forecast', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
    ##Also tried
    sql.write_frame(df, con=db, name='forecast', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')

   **DatabaseError**: Execution failed on sql: SHOW TABLES LIKE %s
   (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
   unable to rollback


   #METHOD 2: using sqlalchemy
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine

   engine =   create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://**username***:**passwd**@***host***:3306/**dbname**")
   conn = engine.raw_connection()
   df.to_sql(name='demand_forecast_t', con=conn,if_exists='replace',    flavor='mysql',index=False, index_label='rowID')
   conn.close()
```

The error message is:

```
**OperationalError**: DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql: SHOW TABLES LIKE %s
(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') unable to rollback
```

Comment: what pandas version are you using?

Comment: I think I know the issue. The dataFrame I am trying to write is too large to write at a time. If I take a subset, the above code works. I guess I will need to write some sort of iteration to do this job at once.

Comment: You need to pass the engine, not the raw connection.

Answer (score 16):

When using sqlalchemy, you should pass the engine and not the raw connection:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://...")
df.to_sql('demand_forecast_t', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Writing to MySQL without sqlalchemy (so with specifying `flavor='mysql'`) is deprecated.

When the problem is that you have a too large frame to write at once, you can use the `chunksize` keyword (see the [docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)). Eg:

```
df.to_sql('demand_forecast_t', engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. I was trying to load a large table into MySQL and as a result of which was getting the error. A simple for-loop to upload data in chunks solved the issue ! Many thanks to everyone who replied.

Comment: You don't need a for loop for this. You can use the `chunksize` keyword.

Comment: How to read sqlalchemy create engine parameters from a config file? Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

For me this was fixed using

```
MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","root","","db" )
```

instead of

```
MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","db" )
```

and then

```
df.to_sql('df',sql_cnxn,flavor='mysql',if_exists='replace', chunksize=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write pandas dataframe in mysql table using mysql flavour(with DBAPI connection) in following ways

step1: install mysqldb module - 
`$ sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev` then 
`$ pip install MySQL-python`

step2: make a connection with mysql
`import MySQLdb` 
`con = MySQLdb.connect("hostname","username","password","databasename")`

step3: write pandas dataframe in mysql table by using df.to_sql 
`df.to_sql('TableName',con = con,flavor='mysql',if_exists='replace', chunksize=100)`