# Pandas 0.20.2 to_sql() using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I'm trying to write a dataframe to a MySQL table but am getting a `(111 Connection refused)` error.

I followed the accepted answer here:
[Writing to MySQL database with pandas using SQLAlchemy, to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631325/writing-to-mysql-database-with-pandas-using-sqlalchemy-to-sql)

Answer's code:

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)
data.to_sql(name='sample_table2', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

...and the `create_engine()` line worked without error, but the `to_sql()` line failed with this error:

```
(mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

How I connect to my MySQL database / table is not really relevant, so completely different answers are appreciated, but given the [deprecation of the MySQL 'flavor' in pandas 0.20.2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), what is the proper way to write a dataframe to MySQL?

Comment: Are you getting any other specifics about why connection refused? Could be entirely unrelated to Python, Pandas, and SQLAlchemy

Comment: No other specifics - however I've been using MySQLdb as my connector to `read_sql()` without issue.  Could it be a difference in read / write permissions?

Comment: Permissions could be it (e.g. if you only have read permissions). Can you trying creating a simple table using another interface (e.g. MySQL Workbench or Sequel Pro)?

Comment: Yeah, I've been creating databases, tables, writing to tables, etc, all using MySQLdb... and reading using `read_sql()`.  I have root access, so I should be able to write, but it may be how I setup the call that is somehow not recognizing that access.

Comment: @openwonk - thanks for your help, I got a tip from Andy Hayden that solved the issue.  Couldn't tell you why, but it worked.  Going to post as the answer.

Comment: @openwon - and after all that, I'm realizing how slow `to_sql()` is for a data set of any relevant size and am chasing the `LOAD DATA INFILE` method...

Comment: Ya, Pandas not meant for more i/o stuff like that... Glad to see you got it to work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from @AndyHayden, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29356874/1240268) was the trick.  Basically replacing `mysqlconnector` with `mysqldb` was the linchpin.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo = False)
df.to_sql(name = 'my_table', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```

Where `[schema]` is the database name, and in my particular case, `:[port]` is omitted with `[host]` being `localhost`.

Comment: Putting it here so that other people can avoid: On @elPastor answer engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:password@localhost:3306/mydbname', echo = False)