# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous when checking value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe created from a CSV where I parse dates in a column named `DATE`. I am looping through the rows and I want to skip everything that has the year of 1980. Here is my code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if df['DATE'].dt.year == 1980:

        continue
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I can print out the date fine. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The fix is actually `row['DATE'].dt.year == 1980`, but please vectorise this. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am looping through rows and adding them to a database. I just want to skip all the records that occur in 1980. Can you elaborate on what vectorise means?

Comment: What database? "vectorize" means you don't have to implement a loop; the code takes care of looping internally.

Comment: My SQL but I have to run the rows through a middleware component that does some data enrichment. Still, I would like to see some examples using MySQL if you could point me to some.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database You can call `to_sql` with a connection object—that should be enough. If you have to run your code through some component, you can use `apply` or some sort of list comprehension. `iterrows` are an anti-pattern with pandas.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.