# How to write(Insert) pandas DatafFrame directly to MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database, pandas

I am extracting data from google sheet and I have to insert that data frame to MySQL localhost database.

I have tried this, and it doesn't work for me: 
[How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database)

```
df.to_sql(con=mydb,schema = 'automate', name='live_nos', if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')
```

I am getting an error. 
TypeError: to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flavor'

When I remove the flavor from this it gives my programming error as follow.

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement.

I am using mysql.connector.connect to make the connection :-

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  passwd="12345678"
)
```

This is my data frame which I extract from the google sheet.

Columns :-          dates     A       B       C      D   E

Row to insert :- 5/1/2019 2712  4854    1273    711 345

I want to insert this pandas data frame into MySQL localhost:-

```
sql = "select * from automate.live_nos"
data = pd.read_sql_query(sql,mydb)
```

The table in MySQL:-

columns :- dates    A   B   C   D   E

Pls help

Comment: Why doesn't `to_sql` work for you?

Comment: It also raises the question, that if you are reading in your data from a mysql db, and then writing to a table, why do you want to use pandas at all?

Comment: I am extracting data frame from a google sheet and I want to insert that data frame to my local database for keeping backup.



I am using mysql.connector.connect to make a connection :- 

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="root",
  passwd="*******"
)

When I use this:
df.to_sql(con=mydb,schema = 'automate', name='live_nos', if_exists='append', flavor='mysql')

I am getting an error.

TypeError: to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flavor'

Comment: When I remove the flavor from this it gives my programming error as follow.               
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement.



I am doing something wrong but not able to find it.

Comment: Ok, you really need to edit your question to provide this additional information. Please include code, and full error messages, and what you are expecting to happen https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask