# Converting Pandas Dataframe into an Mysql backup file

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

i am working on an project on python and now i need to create an mysql backup file for the project, can i convert my dataframe into an mysql file to export to my local machine database later as my code runs on an cloud but i need the db file for importing data

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database)

Comment: this adds dataframe directly to the db i was asking if an backup file could be created, thanks