# I am scraping the researchgate website profiles and store them into database but raises error

Tags: mysql, selenium, web-scraping

I have done this error but got this error now.
the code is here:

```
  `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
import time
import sys
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="danish-khan",
  password="12345",
  db='reseachgate_profiles'
)

cur = mydb.cursor()


#create table
cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Data""")

cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data
               (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                Name varchar(255),
                Institution VARCHAR(255),
                Department varchar(255),
                Citations INTEGER,
                Recommendation INTEGER, 
                Total_Reads INTEGER, 
                Total_research_interest DECIMAL(7,1), 
                Research_items INTEGER,
                Projects INTEGER, 
                Questions  INTEGER,
                Answers INTEGER, 
                Scores  DECIMAL(7,1),
                Followers INTEGER,
                Followings INTEGER
               )''')



login_url = 'https://www.researchgate.net/login'
base_url = "https://www.researchgate.net/institution/Islamia_College_Peshawar/department/Department_of_Chemistry/members"
chrome_driver_path = '/home/danish-khan/scrapers/researchgate/chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)

# default login credential and search query
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
search_query = "Islamia college Peshawar"
results = []
total_profiles = []

with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # retrive url in headless browser
    driver.get(login_url)
    
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-login").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("nova-c-button__label").find_element(By.XPATH, "./..").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.get(base_url)

    time.sleep(10)
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    #names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.display-name')
    #name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]')
    last_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    print('height:',last_height)
    time.sleep(10)
   
    while True:
       # Scroll down to bottom
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
      time.sleep(2)
      
      #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1, 5000);")
      new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
      print('new height:' +str(new_height))
      if new_height == last_height:
          break
      last_height = new_height    
    total_profiles.append(last_height)
    links = '//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]'
    name = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, links))
              )
    print(len(name))
    lenname = len(name)
    total_profiles = total_profiles[0]
    print('total  profiles:', total_profiles)
    #selector = '.display-name'
    selector = '//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]'
    #for i in range(0,1):
    for i in range(0,lenname):
            #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, total_profiles);")
        
            #time.sleep(5)
            links = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, selector))
              )
                     
            links[i].click()

            details = {
                'Name' : driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-e-text--size-xl.nova-e-text--color-grey-900').text,
                'Institution' : '',
                'Department' : driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__info-section-list-item .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text,
                'Citations' : '',
                'Recommendation' : '',
                'Total_Reads' : '',
                'Total_research_interest' : '',
                'Research_items' : '',
                'Projects' : '',
                'Questions' : '',
                'Answers' : '',
                'Scores' : '',
                'Followings' : '',
                'Followers' : ''
        
             }
    
    
            try:
              Institution = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__title .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text
            except:
              Institution = 'N/A'
            
            try:   
              Citations = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Citations = int(Citations.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Citations = 0 
                 
            try:     
              Recommendation =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Recommendation = int(Recommendation.replace(' ', ''))
            except:
              Recommendation = 0 
            
            try:  
              Total_Reads = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text                      
              Total_Reads = int(Total_Reads.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Total_Reads = 0 
            
            try:
              Total_research_interest =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text           
              Total_research_interest = float(Total_research_interest)
            except:
              Total_research_interest = 0.0
            
            try:
              Research_items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text
              Research_items = int(Research_items)
            except:
              Research_items = 0
            
            try:
              Projects = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text
              Projects = int(Projects)
            except:
              Projects = 0

            try:   
              Questions = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Questions = int(Questions)
            except:
              Questions = 0
            
            try:
              Answers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Answers = int(Answers)
            except:
              Answers = 0
            
            
            try:
                Scores = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.profile-header-details-meta-items .nova-e-list__item:nth-child(1)').text
                
                Scores = float(Scores)
            except: 
                Scores = 0
            
            try:                             
              Followings = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Following')]").text.strip('Following').strip('( )')
              
              Followings = int(Followings)
            except:
              Followings = 0
            
            try:                             
              Followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Followers')]").text.strip('Followers').strip('( )')

              Followers = int(Followers)
            except:
              Followers = 0  
            
            
            
            details['Institution'] = Institution 
            details['Citations'] =  Citations
            details['Recommendation'] =  Recommendation
            details['Total_Reads'] = Total_Reads 
            details['Total_research_interest'] = Total_research_interest 
            details['Research_items'] =  Research_items
            details['Projects'] = Projects 
            details['Questions'] = Questions 
            details['Answers'] =  Answers 
            details['Scores'] =  Scores
            details['Followings'] = Followings
            details['Followers'] = Followers
             
            results.append(details)
            driver.back()

            time.sleep(10)
            

profile_details = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(profile_details)

for row in profile_details.itertuples():
            
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Data
                (Name,
                Institution,
                Department,
                Citations,
                Recommendation,
                Total_Reads,
                Total_research_interest,
                Research_items , Projects,
                Questions,
                Answers,
                Scores,
                Followers, 
                Followings)
                VALUES
                ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s", "%s" )''',
                (row.Name,
                row.Institution,
                row.Department,
                row.Citations,
                row.Recommendation,
                row.Total_Reads,
                row.Total_research_interest,
                row.Research_items,
                row.Projects,
                row.Questions,
                row.Answers,
                row.Scores,
                row.Followers,
                row.Followings ) )
                  
            
mydb.commit()
        
print('complete.')
  


mydb.close()
time.sleep(10)
```

driver.close()`

i have trying to scrape all the profiles from this website but raises this error.
This profiles scraping is just like scraping profiles from  linkedin which requires login using selenium.
the output error is:

```
resgt3.py
height: 1932
new height:2394
new height:2394
27
total  profiles: 2394
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resgt3.py", line 121, in <module>
    links[i].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't think this error will be come.
don't know why this error is raising as i already applied scrolling method.

Comment: Look at your scores var, probably you're passing an integer value to a string field in database.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar to this recently, with all the screen scraping, merging multiple data frames together, transforming the final data frame, and pushing the final results to a database.  For one thing I used SQL Server and not MySQL, but that's just a trivial change.  Also, you have A LOT GOING ON HERE.  Based on what I'm seeing, I think your screen scraping process is in good shape, or very close, so let's focus on the part where you push everything into the DB, because there is probably too much here to handle all at once.

Again, assuming everything is scraped correctly, you should probably aggregate everything into a data frame, and then push the DF to a table in your DB.

```
df.to_sql(con=con, name='table_name_for_df', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

Also, you have to create the connection string, so try doing it this way.

```
# Import dataframe into MySQL
import sqlalchemy
database_username = 'ENTER USERNAME'
database_password = 'ENTER USERNAME PASSWORD'
database_ip       = 'ENTER DATABASE IP'
database_name     = 'ENTER DATABASE NAME'
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.
                                               format(database_username, database_password, 
                                                      database_ip, database_name))

df.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='table_name_for_df', if_exists='replace')
```

That should pretty much do it for you, I think.  Or, see the link below if you need more info on this process.

[How to insert pandas dataframe via mysqldb into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database/48116627)