# How to remove/delete first row/column from Data Frame using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to scrape dynamic data from a trading website. I've scraped the whole table and add it to a data frame. Now, I want to delete the first row/column from my data frame and insert it into MySQL. But, I'm unable to delete that row/column.

[image]

Please help me to delete either the first row or column.
I've tried but I can't able to do this :

```
df = df.iloc[: , 1:]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11560/1465043235.py in <module>
----> 1 df = df.iloc[: , 1:]

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Comment: `df` is not a Dataframe, it's a list.

Comment: @timgeb I've stored data using df = pd.read_html(html)

Comment: Which, as per the documentation, returns a list.

Comment: oh ok.. please tell me how to remove the first row having column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.read_html()` returns a list of dataframes. You call the specific dataframes by the index position (Ie: like you did with `df[1]`. So you need to use `.iloc` on the dataframe in your list of dataframes, on index position 1.

```
df = df[1].iloc[: , 1:]
```

Comment: but this gives me an error that : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: thanks, it is working...please tell me how to remove the 1st line containing column names like "ask", "bid" etc

Comment: you can't remove the columns from a dataframe (then it's not a dataframe). what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I wanna insert that data into MySQL and don't know how to do it. I have made a database and a table and made a connection and now I don't know how many columns should i made in my table and what will be the query?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476413/how-to-insert-pandas-dataframe-via-mysqldb-into-database)

Comment: i've used the following code and getting error please check this                       from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/mql5')
con = engine.raw_connection()
df.to_sql('forex', con = con, if_exists='replace')                                                            
 and Error is : DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting