# Importing pickle file into mysql gives an error "ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, pickle

I'm trying to insert data from `.pickle` file into `MySQL`. I'm getting an error `"ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string"`. As I understand, this error happens due to the count of placeholders `(%s)` being greater than the count of values for formating/templating. But in my case they are equal. `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO 'directors'('id', 'first_name', 'last_name') VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (result, ))`

```
import _pickle as cPickle
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb

csv_file = 'NEW_DIRECTORS.csv'
filename = "myfile.pickle"

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
data_to_save = df 

with open(filename,'wb') as file_handle:
    cPickle.dump(data_to_save, file_handle)    
    
with open(filename,'rb') as file_handle:
    result = cPickle.load(file_handle)
    print(result)   

***

id first_name last_name
    0  31       Paul     Aaron
    1  32       Evan  Aaronson
    2  33     Reuben  Aaronson
    3  34     Heikki     Aarva



connection = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','','movies')

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `directors`(`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (result, ))
```

Tried also without quotes:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO directors(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (result, ))
```

Same error.

**Reference**: http://blog.cameronleger.com/2011/05/31/python-example-pickling-things-into-mysql-databases/

```
repr(result)
```

gives me:

```
'   id first_name last_name\n0  31       Paul     Aaron\n1  32       Evan  Aaronson\n2  33     Reuben  Aaronson\n3  34     Heikki     Aarva'
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show `repr(result)`.

Comment: The data needs to be parsed into individual column values.  But it isn't clear which of the numeric values corresponds to `id` (for example in the last row is it 3 or 34?).

Comment: @snakecharmerb it's 34

Answer (score 0):

`result` is a `DataFrame`, so you could convert each row to a tuple and write the tuple to the database:

```py
for t in result.itertuples():
    # We don't want the index, which is the first element.
    values = t[1:]
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO directors(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", values)
conn.commit()
```

This more compact code is equivalent:

```py
row_data = [t[1:] for t in result.itertuples()]
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO directors(id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", row_data)
conn.commit()
```

However note that you would usually just use the dataframe's `to_sql` method, as described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476413/5320906).